# Unable to generate Youtube Developer Key

Tags: youtube, google-api

As per the document at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol, it states to generate Developer Key at  http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/. But clicking on this gives 502 Server error. Please help me to generate a developer key for Youtube API.

Comment: Try use `YouTube Data API (v3)`

Answer (score 0):

The very top of that page which you linked [YouTube API v2.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol) it says:

> Note: The YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated as of
>   March 4, 2014. Please refer to our deprecation policy for more
>   information. Please use the YouTube Data API (v3) for new integrations
>   and migrate applications still using the v2 API to the v3 API as well.

You are three years to late. YouTube v2 doesn't work anymore you need to use [v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/).